# drf_yasg.generators: path component of api base URL http://localhost:8080/ is ignored; use FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME instead

Tags: python, django, swagger

I am using swagger (drf_yasg.generators) with Django  and I get the following error message

Error message is

> drf_yasg.generators: path component of api base URL
> http://localhost:8080/ is ignored; use FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME instead

Here is the swagger

```
class SchemaGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
        schema = super(SchemaGenerator, self).get_schema(request, public)
        schema.basePath = os.path.join(schema.basePath, "")
        return schema


if env.bool("DJANGO_DEBUG"):
    schema_view = get_schema_view(
        openapi.Info(
            title="API",
            default_version="v1",
            description="API endpoints",
        ),
        url="http://localhost:8080/",
        public=True,
        permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
        urlconf="config.urls",
        generator_class=SchemaGenerator,
    )
```

Here is the URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0), name="swagger"),
    path("algo1/", include("core_functions.algo1.urls")),
]
```

Can someone please help with the error?

Comment: I can show you how I have implemented swagger if you want. In your case I don't think you need to specify url in `get_schema_view()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the right configuration of `url` in the `schema_view`.
Please try with the regular Django url configuration deleting the `url` field customization like the following:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from rest_framework import permissions

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title='API',
        default_version='v1',
        description='API endpoints',
        terms_of_service='',
        contact=openapi.Contact(email='your@email.here'),
        license=openapi.License(name="[Add License Name Here]"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

swagger_urlpatterns = (
    re_path(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    re_path(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    re_path(r'^redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
)
```

and then add the following at the end of your `urls.py`:

```
# ...
urlpatterns += swagger_urlpatterns
```

I also suggest to avoid to create a custom `generator_class` in the `schema_view` unless this is strongly needed